# Rails: List of users who upvoted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails application I have an upvote system, it allows people to upvote a pin. Then when a user upvoted a pin I render a list of upvoted pins in the user profile. What I want to do know is to provide a list of the users who upvoted a specific pin.

app/controller/pins_controller.rb

```
def upvote
  @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])

  if @pin.votes.create(user_id: current_user.id)
    flash[:notice] =  "Thank you for upvoting! You can upvote a startup only once."
    redirect_to(pins_path)
  else 
    flash[:notice] =  "You have already upvoted this!"
    redirect_to(pins_path)
  end
end
```

app/controller/users_controller.rb

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @pins_for_user = [] 
    @user.votes.each do |vote| 
    @pins_for_user << vote.pin    
    end
end
```

app/models/pin.rb

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user

    has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :upvoted_users, through: :votes, source: :user

    has_many :rewards, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :rewarded_users, through: :rewards, source: :user

    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
    has_attached_file :logo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }

    end
```

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :pins    
  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :upvoted_pins, through: :votes, source: :pin

  has_many :rewards, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :rewarded_pins, through: :rewards, source: :pin

end
```

app/models/vote.rb

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :pin, counter_cache: true
validates_uniqueness_of :pin_id, scope: :user_id

end
```

I was thinking of using @pin.upvoted_users to provide this list but I didn't succeeded to implement it correctly, any ideas?

Comment: Can you elaborate on issue you faced with upvoted_users. Also did you check gem 'acts_as_votable' - https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Show your `Votes` model class.

Comment: I edited my question with the votes models !

Comment: What does `@pin.upvoted_users` return?

Comment: @dax I can't tell you what it is returning as I don't how to implement it. Can you help me with that?

Comment: join me in this [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57085/temp-room)

Comment: Thanks to Dax Help i went forward ! But when I tried to list the users  who upvoted I have this: #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_User:0x007fc85e1c3058>

Comment: What's the query you're running in ActiveRecord for users who have upvoted?  It would need to be like `Pin.first.votes.users`.  That should give you all `users` who `voted` on the first `Pin`